# DataBinding won't let me change the value

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress

I am trying to implement `DataBinding` in a winform app.  Binding to Text controls work fine so far.  Where my trouble is coming is with DevExpress's `DateEdit` and `LookUpEdit` controls.

This statement works as expected:

```
lkuState.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", Address, "StateID");
```

However this one does not:

```
lkuCounty.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", Address, "County.CountyID");
```

What I mean by works as expected is that the first statement fills the control with the appropriate value AND lets me change that value for saving out.
The second statement fills the control with the appropriate value but does not let me change that value using the control.

I have the same issue with this statement for a `DateEdit` control:

```
uxStartDate.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", WorkerHistory, "StartDate");
```

I am new to databinding  and could have easily made a simple mistake but got me if I've been able to figure out what.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference here is my `Address` and `County` object:

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressID { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    public string AddressLine3 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public string ZipPlus { get; set; }

    public string DirectionsTo { get; set; }

    public string InfoRecipient { get; set; }

    public County County { get; set; }

    public string StateID { get; set; }

    public KeyValuePair<char, string> AddressType { get; set; }

    public string DisplayString { get { return ToString(); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2} {3}", AddressLine1, City, StateID, Zip);
    }
}
public class County
{
    public short? CountyID { get; set; }

    public string CountyName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance I would say it's because `CountyID` is `Nullable`.

Have a look at the following [article](http://xiaonanji.wordpress.com/2009/09/21/data-binding-with-nullable-types-in-c/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you review the following DX resources regarding this:

[WinForms Controls > Products > XtraEditors > Editors Features > Data Binding Overview](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument619)

[DevExpress Search - Bind Nullable Field](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=Bind%20Nullable%20Field&p=T4%7CP1%7C4&d=3)